# Phone authentication still not working even after SafetyNet check

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

After looking at firebase documentation for hours I figured out that the only way to avoid a reCaptcha while phone authentication is using Safety Net. But even after I read the documentation and implementated attest() method, the phone authentication doesn't work.

[Code used for safety net before Phone auth in firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYbJV.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Auth does not require firebase App Check. Firebase App Check if for protecting the data and firebase auth if always protected by google and only the connected app can access. So you need not add Firebase App Check.Or if this is not the case, please make sure that the phoneNumber Verification is enabled
[image: first do this.]
[image: then do this and pick phone number verification]

[image: finally enable it]

but remember, till now firebase has not implemented anything to remove the reCaptcha